# how to login from mobile application and get value of textbox field in web page

Tags: asp.net

I make developing an hybrid appliation in which a user will login by pasing its credential in moblie application and will be redirected to web page .So when we login from web we use session and if we work in windows appliation then we make object of texbox of login form .So how could i access the value from texbox.text of mobile to web page.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use your database in this case, on logged in you can add your required values in database table temporarily.
It will help you in cross platforms like web, mobile, tablet etc.
As database is the generic point in all of them

Comment: i got your point but problem is how could i access the user v=information on web page becuase if it was in web then i could save the username value in session and through this session value i could access it on other page so my question is to how could i use that technology whcih help me to transfer a value from mobile application to web page

Comment: In that case you can use application state instead of saving value in session, which is throughout same for the whole application.